# deployment of asp.net application multiple servers

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, networking, deployment

I want to deploy this application on different servers in case there are a lot of users on one server, so some of them will redirected to the other server.

How do I determine the specifications of the server needed for 200 operations at the same time (for a database application).

Are there any tutorials or articles detailing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to start here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-multicore-scaling-on-numa-hardware